# Content application/json doesn't get escaped while passed in a POST body

Tags: spring-boot, http, postman

Using Spring Boot with Spring Web i'm trying to set up a POST controller which receives a JSON Array in form of a string that is something like this (sent from Postman):

```
[{\"name\":\"...\",\"degrees\":...}] //THIS IS A STRING
```

That is sent to the controller which is:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")

public ResponseEntity<Object> resolveContent(@RequestBody String attributeValue) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //omitted string replace
    try {
        List<Map<String, String>> valueMap = objectMapper.readValue(attributeValue, List.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(valueMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Now, if i remove "\" manually everything works but i'd like to not interfere with a `String.replace()`. Instead would be great to understand why those backslashes are not escaped.
Is that because the content is received as a String and by doing that EVERYTHING inside it is considered a valid character (so no escaping is performed)?

Comment: i'm not getting what u're trying to say.. postman sent everything correctly, I specified "in form of a string" to prevent misunderstandings but was not enough maybe.

Comment: but my question still legit: why postman sends a string(, which very looks like JSON)? why with escapes? and who do you expect to unescape it?

Comment: and: what is the actual outcome/problem?

Comment: Please, try to write one single comment, sometimes comments doesn't refresh properly ending up seeing only one out of three like happened right now.
The problem was that passing a JSON like that was missing \r\n escapes so when it was passed to the objectMapper it couldn't recognize an actual JSON, that's all.